# Applying a condition to one selected column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that is getting the last recorded event and the total recorded events in the year of 2018.

In my query I have to apply the year 2018 to one of the columns only. Here's my code to make it easier for everyone to understand:

```
select 1 as SortId, 'SouthEast' As "Region", NVL(COUNT(*),0) As "Recordable Events YTD"
from Table_name
WHERE 
IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND
IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
AND
to_char(IA_DATE,'YYYY') = '2018'
```

This code will give me the recordable events in the Southeast in the year 2018 and here's the result:

```
    SORTID Region    Recordable Events YTD
---------- --------- ---------------------
         1 SouthEast                     0
```

Here's my second query to show the last event in the Southeast region

```
Select To_CHAR(TRUNC(max(IA_Date)),'MM/DD/YYYY') As "Incident Date"
from DOT.IA_LOG where IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND
IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
```

The result is:

```
Incident Date
-------------
12/18/2017
```

I'm trying to show all the data in one result but when I try to add the second select statement to the first one it gives me a null result for the last incident date because the 2018 condition is applying to it here's my combined query and the result.

```
select 1 as SortId, 'SouthEast' As "Region", NVL(COUNT(*),0) As "Recordable Events YTD",
  To_CHAR(TRUNC(max(IA_Date)),'MM/DD/YYYY') As "Last Recordable Event" 
from Table_name
WHERE 
IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND
IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
AND
to_char(IA_DATE,'YYYY') = '2018' 

    SORTID Region    Recordable Events YTD Last Recordable Event
---------- --------- --------------------- ---------------------
         1 SouthEast                     0
```

How can I apply the condition to one of the columns? What would be the easiest way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cte (common table expression) instead. Hope this helps. Thanks.

```
 with tmp as (select 1 as SortId, 
'SouthEast' As  rgn,
NVL(COUNT(*),0) As YTD
from Table_name
WHERE IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
AND to_char(IA_DATE,'YYYY') = '2018')
select tmp.SortId, 
rgn as "Region",
YTD as "Recordable Events YTD",
To_CHAR(TRUNC(max(IA_Date)),'MM/DD/YYYY') As "Incident Date" 
from DOT.IA_LOG, tmp
where IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
group by sortid,rgn,ytd

Result:
SortId  Region      Recordable Events YTD   Incident Date
1       SouthEast   0                       12/18/2017
```

Comment: When I try to do a sub query I get this error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: I did not test it earlier. I updated my answer to the correct one.

Comment: So you added the sub query in a with statement, would you be able to multiple with statements in the same query?

Comment: Yes, you can use more than one cte table such as:  with t1 as (select * from tbl1), t2 as (select * from tbl2) select * from t1, t2, myTable where <>;

Answer (score 1):

You can use a conditional count, with a case expression inside the count function call, i.e.:

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(IA_DATE,'YYYY') = '2018' then IA_DATE END)
```

and without the overall filter on the year; in situ:

```
select 1 as SortId,
  'SouthEast' As "Region",
  NVL(COUNT(CASE WHEN to_char(IA_DATE,'YYYY') = '2018' then IA_DATE END),0)
    As "Recordable Events YTD",
  To_CHAR(TRUNC(max(IA_Date)),'MM/DD/YYYY') As "Last Recordable Event" from IA_LOG
WHERE 
IA_TYPE_TEXT IN('con_a','con_b','con_c')
AND
IA_PLANT IN('location_a','location_b','location_c')
/
```

The count function only counts not-null values; if the condition isn't met then the result of the case expression is null, so those rows aren't counted.

With dummy data that gives the same results you showed in the question, this gets:

```
    SORTID Region    Recordable Events YTD Last Recordable Event
---------- --------- --------------------- ---------------------
         1 SouthEast                     0 12/18/2017
```

Not directly relevant, but personally I prefer to use `extract()` to compare parts of dates; `count()` can't return null so the `nvl()` isn't needed; and the `trunc()` isn't needed either since your format model doesn't include the time anyway. So you could simplify slightly to something like:

```
select 1 as sortid,
  'SouthEast' as "Region",
  count(case when extract(year from ia_date) = 2018 then ia_date end)
    as "Recordable Events YTD",
  to_char(max(ia_date), 'MM/DD/YYYY') as "Last Recordable Event"
from ia_log
where ia_type_text in('con_a', 'con_b', 'con_c')
and ia_plant in('location_a', 'location_b', 'location_c')
```

which gets the same result. I'd also avoid quoted identifiers, but maybe this is being used directly for display.

Comment: Alex, This worked with this example, but what if I was not trying to count in the first selection, how can I apply the condition to only one of the columns? when I try to do a sub query I get this error: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: I don't understand; what will you do instead of counting, and what subquery? It sounds like you're asking about something completely different.